# git checkout delete directory

Tags: git

I was wondering how i can recover all the files in a directory at once whit git checkout?

You can use the path to the directory to add or remove all files in it at once, like

```
git add /path/to/dir/
```

But when i do

```
git checkout /path/to/dir/
```

i get something like this

```
error: pathspec '/path/to/dir/' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So i have to manually add every file, is there an easier way?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "recover all the files in a directory".  Do you mean "discard all the uncommitted changes to files in that directory"?  Also, note that you shouldn't use absolute paths with `git checkout` - it should be `path/to/dir` instead of `/path/to/dir`, with the path relative to your current directory.

Comment: Could it be the absolute path? I'd assume `git checkout` works with paths relative to the work tree. (E.g., `git checkout path/to/dir` in the working tree)

Comment: @Boldewyn: You get a different error if you use an absolute path, namely `fatal: '/path/to/dir' is outside repository` even if the path leads to a directory in the repository.  I suspect that this is an incorrect relative path problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to determine the branch

`git checkout master` or `git checkout <treeish> -- /path/to/dir`

More info:
http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/18/restoring-a-directory-from-history.html`

Comment: solution: git checkout master -- path/to/dir

Comment: I just tried git checkout -- dir , it is working. He has just forgotten the double `-`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can do it: [watch here for an example](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/18/restoring-a-directory-from-history.html).
The command

```
git checkout <treeish> -- /path/to/dir
```

should be working. In your case you don't specify a branch and it should revert the state of the directory to the last commit.

Maybe you have forgotten `--` after the git checkout command.
(*I did not even know that it could be used without `--` when not dealing with branches.*)